# Is There A Newer WinSock API Past RIO?

Tags: c++, winsock2

**WinSock Registered Input/Output (RIO) API Extensions**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh997032(v%3Dws.11)

> We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft
>   Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service,
>   technology, or API is supported.

Have there been any newer advancements to networking past this api? Is this still an API that new applications should consider using or are there is a better approach networked applications that require the lowest latency possible?

Comment: RIO is still the latest advancement in WinSock low-latency networking.  Only high-performance apps need to consider using RIO, though.  Most apps will be fine using the standard WinSock APIs that have existed for years.

Comment: It doesn't mean that much, feel better [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/ns-mswsock-rio_extension_function_table).